# How to crop too large to fit in memory shapefiles with geoarrow?

Tags: r, gis, apache-arrow

I have a lot of shapefiles I would like to crop, and I decided to give a try to the new `geoarrow` R package.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.3, PROJ 8.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(arrow)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'arrow'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     timestamp
library(geoarrow)
```

Lets create some data

```r
nc <- sf::read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

nc1 <- nc
nc1$id <- 1

nc2 <- nc
nc2$id <- 2

tmpdir <- tempdir(check = TRUE)
```

Write the data as a dataset

```r
lapply(list(nc1, nc2), \(x) {
  write_dataset(x, tmpdir, partitioning = "id")
})
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
```

I can not crop the shapefiles like this:

```r
open_dataset(tmpdir) |> 
  st_crop(c(xmin = -80, xmax = -78, ymin = 34.5, ymax = 36))
#> Error in UseMethod("st_crop"): no applicable method for 'st_crop' applied to an object of class "c('FileSystemDataset', 'Dataset', 'ArrowObject', 'R6')"
```

However, it works if I pull the data in memory before the operation:

```r
open_dataset(tmpdir) |> 
  geoarrow_collect_sf() |> 
  st_crop(c(xmin = -80, xmax = -78, ymin = 34.5, ymax = 36))
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries
#> Simple feature collection with 52 features and 15 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -80 ymin: 34.5 xmax: -78 ymax: 36.00415
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> # A tibble: 52 × 16
#>     AREA PERIMETER CNTY_ CNTY_ID NAME  FIPS  FIPSNO CRESS_ID BIR74 SID74 NWBIR74
#>  * <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 0.128      1.55  1897    1897 Fran… 37069  37069       35  1399     2     736
#>  2 0.17       1.68  1903    1903 Guil… 37081  37081       41 16184    23    5483
#>  3 0.111      1.39  1904    1904 Alam… 37001  37001        1  4672    13    1243
#>  4 0.104      1.29  1907    1907 Oran… 37135  37135       68  3164     4     776
#>  5 0.077      1.27  1908    1908 Durh… 37063  37063       32  7970    16    3732
#>  6 0.142      1.64  1913    1913 Nash  37127  37127       64  4021     8    1851
#>  7 0.219      2.13  1938    1938 Wake  37183  37183       92 14484    16    4397
#>  8 0.201      1.80  1968    1968 Rand… 37151  37151       76  4456     7     384
#>  9 0.18       2.14  1973    1973 Chat… 37037  37037       19  1646     2     591
#> 10 0.094      1.31  1979    1979 Wils… 37195  37195       98  3702    11    1827
#> # … with 42 more rows, and 5 more variables: BIR79 <dbl>, SID79 <dbl>,
#> #   NWBIR79 <dbl>, id <int>, geometry <POLYGON [°]>
```

The problem is that I have a lot of shapefiles which can not be pulled into memory. Any possibility to crop all these shapefiles within `geoarrow`? If not, I will just loop all shapefile individually.

<sup>Created on 2022-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built into geoarrow to help you with this yet - you'll need to loop over the input files and crop the one at a time and write them to your desired output format (e.g., using `geoarrow::write_geoparquet()`).

We're working on writing bindings for sf functions so that the code you posted above will work but the support isn't there yet!